# Permalinks: Why are hypens(-) used over underscores(_) to replace spaces(and other unwanted characters)?

Tags: string, url, uri, permalinks

In some large websystems I have come across lately, *friendly permalinks*, e.g. part of a HTML path that is based on a (often user-specified) string rather than a numerical number, spaces(and other unwanted/disallowed characters that would otherwise need to be url-escaped) are replaced by hyphens (-), and not by underscores (_).

An example:
in the URL `http://example.com/blog/this-is-my-first-post`, `this-is-my-first-post` is a friendly permalink. Using underscores, this would be `http://example.com/blog/this_is_my_first_post`

Is this only a personal preference, or is there a technical reason to use hyphens over underscores?

Hypothetical possibilities I thought of:

- Maybe it matters for Search Engine Optimalization?
- Maybe it is actually important for how HTML paths are interpreted?
- Maybe there is a historical reason?

What I do know:

- Hyphens are treated as word-breaks in most (if not all?) computer systems/programs, e.g. use `ctrl+left/ctrl+right` to move in a sentence_that_uses_underscores vs a sentence-that-uses-hyphens.
- In normal text that a user enters (e.g. names for objects or blogposts), usage of *actual* hyphens is higher than underscores.

Could someone shine some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has spoken:

> Consider using punctuation in your URLs. The URL http://www.example.com/green-dress.html is much more useful to us than http://www.example.com/greendress.html. We recommend that you use hyphens (-) instead of underscores (_) in your URLs.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/76329?hl=en

Comment: Interesting!  According to what I've found [here](http://blog.woorank.com/2013/04/underscores-in-urls-why-are-they-not-recommended/), the reason indeed is that **underscores are not counted as word-separators**, and also that underscores are easily mistaken for spaces on links that have a style with an underline.